# Changing versions of Python in command line

Tags: python, macos

Python 2.5 came installed on my Mac. I downloaded Python 3.2 and have it running in my IDE.  When I open the terminal in Mac and type in Python, it tells me I'm working with 2.5.

1) What do I enter in the command line to change from 2.5 to 3.2?

2) Once I get to 3.2 (using your answer), how do I get back to 2.5 if I want to?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply type `python3.2` instead of just `python` to use python 3.2.

Comment: Or the more generic `python3` if you only have one version of a Python 3 installed.  It's also possible you may need to alter your shell `PATH` depending on how you installed `python3.2`.

Comment: @Ned Deily, thanks, is there a command I can type into the terminal to find out the Path it's installed at?

Comment: And, if you used a Python 3.2 installer from python.org, there is a command script in `/Applications/Python 3.2` that you can launch to modify your shell profile files to add the right framework `bin` directory to your shell `PATH`.